# Which bibliography style does not change the input author names, no shortening, nothing else

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

The biblography ia making me mad. Is there any biblography style that will not alter any of the names and keep them as they are? Like if I give `Paul A. Walker` , it will keep it as “Paul A. Walker”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *many* BibTeX bibliography styles that (a) do not abbreviate first and middle names and (b) format the full name so that the first (and middle) names are shown before the surnames. Four well-known candidates are

- `plain` -- one of the "original" or "base" bibliography styles. Dates back (at least) to the early 1990s. Suitable for numeric citation callout styles.
- `plainnat` -- `natbib`'s re-implementation of the `plain` style.  It recognizes various fields (e.g., `url`, `doi`, `isbn, etc) that are ignored by`plain`. Suitable for numeric, author-year (aka "harvard"), and superscript citiaton call-out styles. Should be used with the`natbib` citation management package.
- `unsrt` -- same formatting (and vintage) as `plain`, but entries in the  bibliography are not sorted alphabetically by authors' surnames. Instead, the entries' order of appearance in the bibliography corresponds to the order the entries are first `\cite`-ed in the body of the document.
- `unsrtnat` -- `natbib`'s reimplementation of the `unsrt` style.

Comment: Why are the names getting shortened? WHY?

Comment: @user3237995 - You're not telling me what you're doing, so I have no idea how to respond. Please post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior you would like to see fix. Please also be sure to indicate whether you ran LaTeX, then BibTeX, then LaTeX twice more *after* you changed the `\bibliographystyle` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **\relax** command while defining the author name inside curly braces.

Here is an example from the bibliography of a LaTeX document I am currently working on.

```
@misc{uncitral2,
    author    = {{\relax United Nations Commission on International Trade Law}},
    title     = {{UNCITRAL} Model Law on International Commercial Arbitration (1985), with amendments as adopted in 2006},
    howpublished = {\url{http://www.uncitral.org/uncitral/en/uncitral_texts/arbitration/1985Model_arbitration.html}},
    note = {Accessed: 2018-04-30}
}
```

The above command basically tells LaTeX to take a chill pill and prevents it from shortening the author name. You can, as well, place some parts of a long name or other author names outside the curly braces of \relax command to allow them to be shortened as usual.